# How to delete the lines in a file not starting with numbers and have no space to the left in linux using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have an input file like below:

```
       48819  5.05780805e+00  1.98145833e+00  1.68575829e+02
       48815  6.06856107e+00  1.98165597e+00  1.68575500e+02
*KEYWORD
$TIME_VALUE =  5.0000443e+00
$STATE_NO = 52
$Output for State 52 at time = 5.00004
*NODE
       48027  4.84536486e+01  6.01658273e+00  1.49520029e+02
       48028  4.85477927e+01  5.02370845e+00  1.49519394e+02
```

I have to delete all the lines which start with non-numeric data. Please note that the data is space separated and that the text with special characters start from the position 1, so there is no space before that text in the line.

Any suggestion with `sed -i` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*[0-9]/p' file
       48819  5.05780805e+00  1.98145833e+00  1.68575829e+02
       48815  6.06856107e+00  1.98165597e+00  1.68575500e+02
       48027  4.84536486e+01  6.01658273e+00  1.49520029e+02
       48028  4.85477927e+01  5.02370845e+00  1.49519394e+02
```

This uses the `-n` to "suppress automatic printing of pattern space", so that we only print the lines we want. In this case, the ones starting with 0 or more spaces followed by a digit.

To use `sed -i`, you can say `sed -n -i.bak ...` in order to have in-place replacement, keeping a `file.bak` file as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

With **sed**:

```
sed -rn '/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]/p' File
```

Print only lines beginning with one or more space/tab, followed by a digit.

For in-place change:

```
sed -rni '/^[[:space:]]+[0-9]/p' File
```